# Unexpected output from Filtering Multiple Conditions with dplyr filter

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have a dataframe with 3 variables: report_epiweek, report_epiyear, and Freq_case.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)    
mydata<-data.frame(report_epiweek=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 
                       report_epiyear=c(2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019), 
                       Freq_case=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,2,6,2,3,4,5,7,8,34,2,0,6,3,1))
```

I would like to produce a bar chart using ggplot2. I want to filter out the weeks with 0 values from 2018 (weeks 1 to 6). My understanding of the filter function was that you could filter rows based on multiple conditions (from https://suzan.rbind.io/2018/02/dplyr-tutorial-3/):

Filtering based on multiple conditions
The above examples return rows based on a single condition, but the filter option also allows AND and OR style filters:

filter(condition1, condition2) will return rows where both conditions are met.

filter(condition1, !condition2) will return all rows where condition one is true but condition 2 is not.

filter(condition1 | condition2) will return rows where condition 1 and/or condition 2 is met.

filter(xor(condition1, condition2) will return all rows where only one of the conditions is met, and not when both conditions are met.

```
mydata %>% 
  mutate(report_epiweek=as.numeric(report_epiweek)) %>% 
  filter(!Freq_case==0 & report_epiyear==2018) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=report_epiweek, y=Freq_case))+
  geom_col()+
  ggtitle("EpiCurve") + 
  facet_grid(. ~ report_epiyear)+ 
  theme_bw()+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90), legend.position = "bottom", legend.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 8))
```

This yields the following graph. 
[image: epicurve]

It appears that the filter is filtering out all records that have a report_epiyear of 2018, but I want to have a graph where the filtered records are those that have a Freq_case of 0 and are in 2018. This would leave my Freq_case 0 in 2019 untouched. (and I would be able to see the other 2018 values).

I'm not sure if I'm just not understanding how to use filter. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `!` as you have written it only applies to the first argument (`Freq==0`). Add parentheses around the two components of the `&` conditional so that they are joint before you invert it with `!`.

```r
mydata %>% 
  mutate(report_epiweek=as.numeric(report_epiweek)) %>% 
  filter(!(Freq==0 & report_epiyear==2018)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=report_epiweek, y=Freq))+
  geom_col()+
  ggtitle("EpiCurve") + 
  facet_grid(. ~ report_epiyear)+ 
  theme_bw()+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90), legend.position = "bottom", legend.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 8))
```

[image: EpiCurve Plot]

Comment: I tried your suggestion; the first 5 weeks still appear on the graph.

Comment: For which year? I have uploaded an image of the plot produced by my answer.

Comment: I got the same output. I'm looking to not have the first 6 weeks of 2018 (sorry I said 5 before), where the Freq_case=0

Comment: No I understand what you're looking for. I used your same dataset and the code from my answer produced the plot above, which I believe is what you're looking for, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside the facet.

`facet_grid(~ report_epiyear, scales = "free", space = "free" )`